# Simplest remote IR?

Tags: wireless, infrared

What I need is: when I turn on a IR led, a receiver circuit in the other side would have 5V or 0V depending on the state of the transmitter. Simple.

I have a IR transmitter and a photo-diode for receive, those used on every IR control and receiver. I don't know how the photo-diode works so how should the circuit be? Should I use a transistor configured in saturation / cut-off working with the receiver?

Feel free to recommend me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phototransistor configured as an inverter:

```
5V ----+
       |
       /
       \  47k
       / 
       |
       +----- Logic output (inverted)
       |
  \   /
  \  |    NPN
      \>  Phototransistor
       |
      ---
       -
```

A phototransistor is like a photodiode, but has a significantly increased gain. So when light shines on it (or IR, if it has an IR filter) it will pull down the output, conducting a few mA. A photodiode could do the same job, but you'd need a much greater (x100-1000) resistor, and this might be overwhelmed by the any load impedance.

You could put another inverter on the output to get a logic signal of the correct polarity (or to buffer it, as it won't take much load current.) Here is one possible inverter circuit:

```
          5V ----+
                 |
                 /
                 \  10k
                 / 
                 |
                 +--- output
                 |
          10k   /
Input ---/\/\/--|   NPN
                \>  2N3904
                 |
                ---
                 -
```

Comment: I bought a phototransistor but it looks like the dude one the shop gave me a photodiode. How can I know which one is it? (it looks like a white led)

Comment: They look identical. I suppose the only way to test it is to wire up this circuit - if it works, then you have a phototransistor.

Comment: Ok. I'll try your circuit. Just on more thing: the emitter in your circuit would be the cathode (the short leg), right?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try it both ways, there should be no harm due to the low voltages and very low current.

Comment: I tried it. The behaviour is very weird (I'm not using the transistor circuit yet). When I measure voltage in the output, it goes from 200 mV to 4V, but the change is not when I turn the led on, the change is when I cover it from normal light with my fingers.

Comment: Well, the sensitivity is very high. Replace the 47k with a 4.7k - it might work better.

Comment: Yes, but looks like it is receiving any kind of light, not just IR. Do I need some kind of filter?

Comment: You can pick up a phototransistor with an IR filter on it. Be aware it will still pick up some ambient light as ambient light contains IR. Here is one example: http://uk.farnell.com/vishay/bpw85/phototransistor-t1/dp/1045380

Comment: If you place what you think is the emitter in a simple circuit with a power supply and a resistor then with a phone camera look at it it should look lit up(this doesn't work with iPhones but does with sonys and nokias).

Comment: @Thomas: if you swap the resistor and phototransistor you don't need the extra inverter.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find that without modulation the circuit (like one posted by Thomas O) will be extremely sensitive to ambient illumination. When the lightning conditions change the output will stick to either 0 or 5V. In theory you could work it around by adding a biasing circuit driven by a very low bandwidth feedback loop (so that slow illumination changes are cancelled and your signal is not) but it's much easier to modulate the signal driving your IR LED - that's what most (all?) commercial circuits do.

Answer (score 2):

Look at 3-pin 38 KHz IR receiver. Its best possible receiver part with very low cost.
If your signal channel can comply to return to zero requirement (no information bit=1 state of signal is longer than milliseconds) then you can use standard parts like this.

Sorry for radioshack reference, but its first link on google: http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2049727

Comment: Unfortunately the 38 kHz receiver you linked to is only capable of receiving 38 kHz encoded signals. It is designed to not pick up ambient light, or in this case, slow pulsing IR.

Comment: Exactly. I need something more simple.

Comment: Agree, but. Attempt to transmit 1-bit DC over noisy channel (ambient IR environment) is not small feat. Unless your range and optical path is fixed and around few millimeters. In reality the Db range involved can vary up to 80-100Db. Its more like true AM radio.

Comment: I understand now, the ambient IR contamination, makes my  DC channel impossible. I'll have to go for the modulated channel.

Comment: This is definitely the right approach - there is a tremendous amount of 'hard stuff' done in that little 3-pin can, and it costs peanuts to buy.   If you're only trying to convey on or off, then you don't have to worry about any of the IR signalling schemes - just flash your LED at 38K in one condition and leave it off in the other.

Comment: IR RC decoders have a filter which removes any signal which is too far from the center frequency (38 kHz). It doesn't work for continous signals.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others said, use a modulated signal. It will give you a much more reliable transmission. For the receiver I often use [Vishay](http://www.vishay.com/ir-receiver-modules/), which has a wide offering in carrier frequencies, packages and protocols.

In its most basic form the transmitter is just an astable multivibrator driving the IR LED. But the [AGC](http://www.vishay.com/ir-receiver-modules/agc-list/) (Automatic Gain Control) in the receiver is not designed to receive a continuous carrier. So it's better to simulate some RC protocol and choose a receiver for that protocol.

For the transmitter you can use a small microcontroller like the AVR [ATTiny4](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8127.pdf) or Microchip [PIC10F200](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41239D.pdf). Both have an internal oscillator and work without any external components, then all you need is a resistor, a transistor and the IR LED.

While the AVR is more performant than the PIC, this is not required here, and overmore: the accuracy of the "calibrated" internal oscillator for the AVR is a disappointing 10%, while the PIC is 1% accurate. So the PIC may be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The modulated route is the way to go.  But try the other untill you are sufficiently frustrated with it.  Use a 555 timer in the transmitter.  This is still very simple and cheap.